# Importing tensorflow error: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror

I have installed Python 3.8.3 and `tensorflow` 2.3.1 on Windows 10 64-bit but when I try to import `tensorflow`, I face the following error

```py
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Sometimes [a quick diagnosis with a DLL/PYD dependency check tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944065/tensorflow-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-pywrap-tensorflow-inter#69874313) could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to check TensorFlow is correctly installed or not.

Run this command:

**pip freeze**

Comment: i run this command and i found there is  "tensorflow==2.3.1" in the list

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794

Comment: Try this solution. This the same error you might be facing

Comment: there is only the questions ,they are not providing any solution.

Comment: Do your laptop had GPU? Try to re install tensorflow in the virtual environment of conda according to your requirements.
[link]https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup
[link]https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/